# PUT request in Angular not sending updated data within XHR Header

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner and new to AngularJS. I am trying to build an Edit/Update function.

The edit function doesn't do much, it just copies the model data to the Form inputs:

```
  // Edit post
  $scope.editPost = function(post){
    $scope.title = post.title;
    $scope.link = post.link;
  };
```

The Update function should (after clicking the Update Button) take the edited data of the inputs, to update the post model:

```
 // Update post
  $scope.updatePost = function(post){
    posts.update(post, {
      title: $scope.title,
      link: $scope.link
    }).success(function() {
      ToastService.show('Post updated');
    });
  };
```

The Edit Part works, when I edit the title input and click the Submit Button of the Edit Form, it sends a PUT request, but it seems to doesn't send the updated data within the PUT - it just sends a request with the original data.

The posts.js service:

```
angular.module('bidrp')
.factory('posts', [
'$http',

function($http){
  var o = {
    posts: [{title:"hey", upvotes:123}]
  };
  o.update = function(post) {
    return $http.put('/posts/' + post.id, post).success(function(data){
      o.posts.push(data);
    });
  };
```

Template where Post is displayed and editPost is triggered:

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy: '-upvotes'">
  <md-button class="md-icon-button md-accent" aria-label="Vote-Up" ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)">
    <i class="material-icons">thumb_up</i>
  </md-button>
  {{post.upvotes}}
  <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
    <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
      {{post.title}}
    </a>
    <span ng-hide="post.link">
      {{post.title}}
    </span>
  </span>
  <span>
    posted by <a ng-href="#/users/{{post.user.username}}">{{post.user.username}}</a>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a href="#/posts/{{post.id}}">Comments</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="editPost(post); showEditForm = ! showEditForm">Edit</a>
    <a href="#" ng-click="deletePost(post)">Delete</a>
  </span><br>
  <div ng-show="showEditForm" ng-include="'home/_edit-post.html'"></div>
</div>

<div ng-include="'home/_add-post.html'"></div>
```

_edit-post.html partial:

```
<form ng-submit="updatePost(post)">
  <h3>Edit post</h3>
  <div ng-include="'home/_form-post.html'"></div>
</form>
```

_form-post.html partial:

```
<md-input-container>
  <label>Title</label>
  <input required type="text" ng-model="title">
</md-input-container>

<md-input-container>
  <label>Link</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="link">
</md-input-container>

<md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary">Submit</md-button>
```

What am I doing wrong, how can I send the edited form data within the PUT request?

Comment: can you share your template ?

Comment: yes, added templates to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because, your, are just passing the original post object  generated by ngRepeat to the update function not the $scope.post. When using ng-model="post" this will be attached to the $scope object.

You do not need the editPost function, the new data are already passed to $scope.title/$scope.title by ngModel directive (doing this will re-update the $scope.tile, $scope.link with the old values):

```
// Edit post
  $scope.editPost = function(post){
    $scope.title = post.title;
    $scope.link = post.link;
  };
```

Comment: Makes sense. But I don't understand how to fix it (I am really new to angular and trying to build simple CRUD features for learning).

Comment: Thanks, but how can I pre-fill the inputs when i dismiss the edit function?

Comment: the ng-model directive will fill the the $scope, so ng-model="title" will be available in $scope.title

Comment: finally got it. I removed the edit function. Also had to seperate the addPost and updatePost Form, because updateForm uses ng-model="post.title", while the addPost form uses ng-model="title". But it works now. thank you.